# Need to trim blank space in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

Unable to trim blank space in below data in my table. column data type is VARCHAR2(650 CHAR). I tried trim function to eliminate blank space. but that is not working for me.

DATA in my table:

```
'xxxxxxxxxx yyyyyyyyy - 12/7/14 - 12/13/14   '
'xxxxxxxxxx yyyyyyyyy - 12/7/14 - 12/13/14       '
'xxxxxxxxxx yyyyyyyyy - 12/7/14 - 12/13/14   '
```

I want trim the data like below

```
'xxxxxxxxxx yyyyyyyyy - 12/7/14 - 12/13/14'
'xxxxxxxxxx yyyyyyyyy - 12/7/14 - 12/13/14'
'xxxxxxxxxx yyyyyyyyy - 12/7/14 - 12/13/14'
```

Could you please help me on this.

Comment: Not working is not an excuse. Show what have you tried so far.

Comment: How are you determining that there are trailing spaces? What query or tool are you using to see them?

Answer (score 4):

Use `Trim` Function

```
select Trim(trailing ' ' from 'xxxxxxxxxx yyyyyyyyy - 12/7/14 - 12/13/14   ') from dual
```

or Use `Rtrim`

```
select RTrim('xxxxxxxxxx yyyyyyyyy - 12/7/14 - 12/13/14   ') from dual
```

Comment: No if the same data present in table with same data type then its not working for me

Comment: maybe there are not spaces in your column, perhaps there are rare characters

Comment: its not working.. is there any way to get separate second date only  from the string.

Comment: Yes you can, using regexp_substr

Comment: check this select ascii(substr(yourdata,-1)) from table what does this return

Comment: spyga, you could get the 2nd date only through regex: `REGEXP_SUBSTR('xxxxxxxxxx yyyyyyyyy - 12/7/14 - 12/13/14   ', '\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2}', 1, 2)` - If you want to get the first date change the last parameter `2` to `1`.

Comment: @spyga `ascii 52` is `4`, so, looks like there are not spaces at  the end of your string

Answer (score 1):

I would use `REGEXP_REPLACE()` in the event that there were other whitespace charaters like tabs in there:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(mydata, '\s+$') AS mydata
  FROM mytable
```

Hope this helps. If `TRIM()` isn't working then I suspect you have something other than spaces trailing.

If you know that the data is going to end with a digit, you might also try the following:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(mydata, '\D+$') AS mydata
  FROM mytable
```

The `\D` in the regex matches everything but a digit, so any trailing characters not a digit `0-9` will be trimmed.

Comment: I can't explain why it isn't working, can you give an example? See SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/39515 - trailing characters trimmed.

Answer (score 1):

We also can trim left and right side blank spaces using below approach

```
SELECT LTrim(RTrim('xxxxxxxxxx yyyyyyyyy - 12/7/14 - 12/13/14   ')) FROM dual
```